# How to wrap the query in a view in the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, firebird, hibernate-mapping

I need to extract a view that is coming out of a @Query in my repository to a table in another database, I'm in a Multi-Tenacy connection, in it I have a view that I can visualize, and this view wanted to transport it directly to a table of another bank that is connected with the API,
it would look a bit like this example:
[site](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-jpa-entity-to-view-or-sql-query-with-hibernate/)

```
@Repository
public interface example extends JpaRepository<example,Long>{

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW example AS SELECT " +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "   example," +
            "   example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example," +
            "    example" )
    List<Object> projection();`
```

this view above it returns everything as expected, now I wanted it to go straight to a table in another bank in my Multi-Tenacy connection

My @GetMapping

```
@GetMapping
public List<Object> projecao(){
    return repository.projection2();
}
```

Comment: I don't follow - why would you add a 'projection' method set to return a List<Object>  that really just creates a view object in the database? Creating a view is a one time operation that doesn't return objects, not something your app would need to (or even should) call repeatedly. The article you've linked shows how to use a view and back it in Hibernate with an entity for queries - how does this tie into a different database exactly?

Comment: i followed this classroom for multi database connections : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2dGEBj2750

Comment: now I have a @Query that returns a view, and this query would like to apply to another database

Comment: The classroom should have told you how to deal with entities in multiple databases - why is this different, what problems are you hitting?

Comment: the problem is that this reading that returns me to the query, I can't get it to fall into a table in another bank, but I see that what I want would be wrong or unlikely to happen

Comment: 1) Firebird doesn't have `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` (it is `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` or `RECREATE VIEW`), 2) that is DDL, and you can't execute it as a query and expect it to return a list of something. It is unclear to me what you're asking.